# Out of memory second run

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, csv, memory

Something unexpected happens when I try to load a large array from a CSV file. The file has 100000 rows and 100 columns (80mb). I have tried numerous ways to load the CSV quickly (because speed is of essence). The code below works fine the first time, but when I run it a second time either variable title (String) or redim arrRaw (Variant) gives a 'out of memory' error. After restarting Excel it works fine for one time again.
They are both locally declared variables. I have tried to use public declaration and then erasing the array, but this diddent work. My system shows no problem with the RAM memory. Is there a work around (or a solution) to this problem?

```
Open filepath For Binary Access Read As #i
Get #i, , res
Close i

title = Split(Right(Left(res, Len(res) - 1), Len(Left(res, Len(res) - 1)) - 1), vbLf)
columnsArr = UBound(Split(title(1), ";"))
rowsArr = UBound(title)

ReDim arrRaw(1 To rowsArr, 1 To columnsArr)

Call timerClock(True)

For i = 0 To rowsArr
    TmpAr = Split(title(i), ";")
    For j = 0 To UBound(TmpAr) - 1
        If IsNumeric(TmpAr(j)) Then
            arrRaw(i + 1, j + 1) = TmpAr(j)
        Else
            arrRaw(i + 1, j + 1) = 0
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you have setted all variables to "nothing" after the work is done?

Anyway, I want to share a tip with you: if you are working with strings in "title", replace all "Right" and "Left" functions with "Right$" and "Left$". You'll get a 5 or 10% faster result. Also, try to not do the same two or more times, like:

```
Left(res, Len(res) - 1)
```

...It will be better to assign it to a variable and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on what you are assigning **i** (`i = FreeFile`...?) but perhaps this alternate method of a free file handle will clear the file handle a bit better.

```
Open filepath For Binary Access Read As #1
Get #1, , res
Close #1
```

In any event, your own code should likely be using `Close #i`.